# GKE pod health status in Google Cloud GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Are there any metrics I can use to know if pods are in the running state or errored-out, crashloopbackoff state etc in GKE Google Cloud?

Basically I want a metric I can export to Stackdriver that can tell if my jobs are running healthy pods or pods have errors and no pods are running( Evicted, crashloopbackoff etc. )

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation Cloud Monitoring supports the following metric types from Google Kubernetes Engine:

[Kubernetes metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_kubernetes)

I believe you can use for your case:

[image]